# Approximating a transformed volume

Tags: approximation, volume

A solid ellipsoid $E$ which contains $(1,2)$ is transformed to a region $T(A)$ using $T(x,y) = (x^2 +y^2, xy)$. Approximate the volume of $B$ if the volume of $A$ is $0.1$.

I have absolutely no idea where to begin. My first idea is to use the determinant, but $T$ is non-square. I am completely lost... any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of the Jacobian ?

Comment: Yes... but what do I do with the Jacobian determinant.

Comment: Do you know what it is and what it means ?

Comment: Hmm I probably don't understand. I know that the determinant represents the area. In this case I'm not sure what it is the area of.

Comment: It's not an area. It's an area scaling factor.

Comment: So if I multiply the Jacobian of T at some point (not sure which one) by the volume of A, then I should get the volume of B?

Comment: Would it be at (1,2)?

Comment: Where else could it be ?